# Create movie from images using GStreamer

Tags: c#, image, video, gstreamer

I want to create movie / video from some images using GStreamer in c#. Is there any approach to achieve this task?

Regards
Vipul

Comment: I would read the doco for GStreamer and follow any examples they may have.  Is that what you mean?  Do you have any code to show?  This will help us help you. 
 Otherwise SO sadly isn't really a place where people write code for you.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Did you look at the GSTREAM Editing classes?  https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-editing-services/html/

Comment: Is there any sample to create movie using images using GStreamer. I found most of sample which demonstrate Streaming of video. I do not find any sample for this kind of case. like use of GESImageSource https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-editing-services/gesimagesource.html?gi-language=c

Comment: Or GESMultiFileSource https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-editing-services/gesmultifilesource.html?gi-language=c

Comment: There is no c# binding for GES services. http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/c-bindings-for-GStreamer-Editing-Services-td4540432.html So GStream Editing Classes like GESMultiFileSources or GESImageSource class will not be found for c#. Is there any alternate approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of how you can do this (not tested).

You can try to use [imagefreeze](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-imagefreeze.html) element which creates a continuous video from a single image input (frame).

**Example pipeline:**
[image]

**Procedure:**

1. Start pipeline with 1st image's path set in `location` property of `filesrc` (e.g. image1.png)
2. When you want to switch to another image

   - set pipeline to state STATE_READY
   - change `filesrc`'s `location` to a new image (e.g. image2.png)
   - set pipeline to state STATE_PLAYING
3. When there are no more images, send EOS (end of stream) downstream to properly stop recording and then set pipeline's state to STATE_NULL to stop pipeline.